# Match all timecodes between two timecodes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to generate multiple routes that are all based on timecodes of a video. One same route is used throughout a certain time frame.

**Is it possible with regex to get all values between (and including) two timecodes?**

Some [regex do compare numbers](https://regex101.com/r/hG2iU7/7). This one matches all numbers greater than 954.

```
/[1-9]\d{3,}|9[6-9]\d|9[5-9]{2}/g
```

But is it possible to compare the followings ? (By replacing the naive comparisons by regular expressions)

```js
00:00<00:01 // should get 00:00 and 00:01 but not 00:02
00:00<00:02 // should get 00:00, 00:01 and 00:02
```

**Additional context**: Using [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) I can do things like `/:lang(en|es)` to match english or spanish. I was experimenting on passing in `/:timecode(regexp)` to match any timecode between two timecodes.

This would provide one same route route for `/00:00` and `/00:01`

Comment: I suggest you convert timecodes to time variable, then you can easily do the math.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Your linked regex matches a time range rather than times, can you clarify? Anyway, given a time start and a time end, you need more than pure regex to match all the times between. However, a language could generate a regex that matches them (but would probably do a better job without regex)

Comment: @PoulBak I’m using node. I know how to generate routes with a loop but that would be a huge loop => regex?

Comment: I think the question is, how much trouble do you want to go through to validate the timecode?

Comment: The regex for the general case of a range is very ugly, long and painful to write. Regex is not the best tool for the job. I recommend converting to a single integer value (for example, the number of seconds since midnight, or since the last hour, etc) and check if the value is within low/high values using math.

Comment: a question should be self-contained. People don't click on external links just to understand it

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to create such regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, using a regular expressions is probably not the best solution. Depending on the tools, there might be better solutions. However, it is somewhat possible.

## How to create the regex

Let's assume our timecodes do always have the following format: `mm:ss`. You might want to match all timecodes from `22:22` to `77:77`. This means the regex shall match when one of the following statements is true.

- Timecode starts with `2` and the rest of the string is `2:22` or higher.
- Timecode starts with `3`, `4`, `5` or `6`.
- Timecode starts with `7` and the the rest of the string is `7:77` or lower.

This means at least one the following three regular expressions must match:

- `/2{2:22 or higher}/`
- `/[3-6]\d:\d\d/`
- `/7{7:77 or lower}/`

This means the final regular expression would look something like the following. The parts surrounded by curly braces (`{}`) will be resolved later.

```
/2{2:22 or higher}|[3-6]\d:\d\d|7{7:77 or lower}/
```

Now, we have to resolve `{2:22 or higher}` and `{7:77 or lower}`. A string of the form `x:xx` is `2:22` or higher, when one of the following statements are true.

- The string starts with `2:` and the rest of the string is `22` or higher.
- The string starts with `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` or `9`.

Therefore, `{2:22 or higher}` can be written as

```
/2:{22 or higher}|[3-9]:\d\d/
```

Now we have the following.

```
/2(2:{22 or higher}|[3-9]:\d\d)|[3-6]\d:\d\d|7{7:77 or lower}/
```

You can repeat this steps until no parts surrounded by curly braces (`{}`) are left. The result might look as below.

```
/2(2:(2[2-9]|[3-9]\d)|[3-9]:\d\d)|[3-6]\d:\d\d|7(7:(7[0-7]|[0-6]\d)|[0-6]:\d\d)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/AsfRQt/1/tests

Comment: This is really cool, thanks a lot. I was stuck at this stage before I saw your answer `(([0-5].[0-9]?|60)(?:[:])([0-5].[0-9]?|60))`... Far from the solution! Thanks again

Comment: @AstenMies I just realized that having a timecode with more then 60 seconds behind the colon is not very reasonable. :D However, I guess the procedure is still comprehensible.

Comment: Yep I thought you must have a very unusual watch ;) But indeed it doesn't matter much, it's comprehensible